# if I upgrade my kernel, do I need to do anything with grub?

Tags: grub2, kernel

so I upgraded my kernel via

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

Do I need to do anything with grub?

I've found kernel upgrading guides where they upgraded grub and the other didn't.

which one is which?

Even this official Ubuntu page  (click [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_-_Xenial_Xerus)) says nothing of grub

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to do anything with grub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, `grub-install` runs automatically. But if you not sure, you can run `sudo grub-install` manually

Answer (score 2):

No, Grub will find it automatically.

Taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process#Boot_loader_phase

> GRUB 2 [...] has two (optionally three) stages and
>   being capable of automatic detection of various operating systems and
>   automatic configuration. The first-stage loader (stage1) is loaded and
>   executed either by the BIOS from the Master boot record (MBR) or by
>   another boot loader from the partition boot sector. **Its job is to
>   discover and access various file systems that the configuration can be
>   read from later.**

You should see the kernel behind the distro in the Grub menu. If not (or you want to be sure the correct kernel is loaded) you can check after reboot by typing `uname -r` in the terminal to check which kernel you are running.